# How do I check a user login and start the session

Tags: php, session

So my website has a login but the user must be logged in to view every page I don't want them to login every time I want to add a session so they only login once what do I need to add in my code so they don't need to login until they hit logout.  http://pastebin.com/dbE3mAKV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your login page add this;

```
 session_start();  
 $_SESSION['usename'] = $username;  
 $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
```

and on all other pages add this:

```
 session_start();  

 $username = $_SESSION['usename'];  
 $password = $_SESSION['password'];  

 # Do database check on $username and $password  
 if($username =='test' AND $password =='pass1'){  
     echo "logged in";  
 } else {  
     die("please log in first!");    
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [session_start](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) to start your session (must be called on every page to work). For more information on sessions in general check out the [sessions page](http://us.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php) of PHP.net

Answer (score 1):

Login page

```
<?php
session_start(); 

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "", "", "");

//if post and encryption
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){

    $userEmail=strip_tags(trim($_POST['userEmail']));
    $userPassword=SHA1(trim($_POST['userPassword']));

    //Check to see if the user left any space empty! For browsers that do not support the HTML5 'required' atribute.
    if($userEmail==""||$userPassword=="") 
        { 
        $error="Please fill in all of the information"; 
        } else {


    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT userID FROM users WHERE userEmail = ? and userPassword = ? LIMIT 1")) {
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $userEmail, $userPassword);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        if($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
            $_SESSION['Email'] = $userEmail;
            $stmt->close();
            //go to next page
            header ("location: nextpage.php");    
        }
        $error="Email and Password do not match, please try again."; 
    }
}}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
    <!--Display errors-->
<div class="errorbox">
    <?php if(isset($error)){?><strong class="error"><?php echo $error;?></strong><?php } ?>
</div>
```

### Login

```
                    <form action="#" name="loginform" method="post" >

                    <!--change input type to email if desired but then Spanish accented characters will fail validation -->
                    <label>Email </label>
                    <input type="text" class="styleinput" name="userEmail" maxlength="50" title="Enter Your email" autocomplete="off" placeholder="enter email" required/><br />

                    <label>Password </label>
                    <input type="password" class="styleinput" name="userPassword" maxlength="50" title="Enter Your Password" autocomplete="off" placeholder="enter password" required/>

                    <a href="help.php" class="stylelink"> Forgot your password? </a>
                    <input type="submit" name="Submit" class="stylesubmit" value="Submit">


                    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

every other page that user must be logged in

```
<?php 
session_start(); 

if(!isset($_SESSION['Email'])){
header("location:home.php");
}
?>
```

your code - Also edit above code to fit your site and don't forget to encrypt password on registration page.